# How to fix error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): meetups.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get data from my api, then i'm using match params and its working( i checked)
But when i do the map this error is happening and i don't know why:

**×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): meetups.map is not a function**

```
export default function Details({ match }) {
  const [meetups, setMeetups] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadMeetups() {
      const response = await api.get(`list/${match.params.id}`);
      setMeetups(response.data);
    }
    loadMeetups();
  }, [match.params.id]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        {meetups.map(meetup => (
          <>
            <header>
              <p>{meetup.title}</p>
              <aside>
                <button type="button">Editar</button>
                <button type="button">Cancelar</button>
              </aside>
            </header>
            <Meetup>
              <div>
                <img
                  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRCbLCtAN0pPHM3cEtNR0tEpFf6r6AIHOUMjOnAVl2srJO-5lQP"
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
              <article>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
                Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an 
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen 
                book. 
              </article>
              <footer>
                <p>SOME DATE</p>
                <p>SOMEWHERE</p>
              </footer>
            </Meetup>
          </>
        ))}
      </Content>
    </Container>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you logged `response.data` and checked that it's an array, and not an object or something else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. It should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future reader who is scanning a list of search results. Your current title is meaningless. Using a clear, descriptive title also helps you get an answer more quickly, as people who can answer it can see what it's about, which your current title does not provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand lets recreate an error:

```
var x = {}
console.log(x.map) // undefined
x.map() // Uncaught TypeError: x.map is not a function ...
```

I suspect the you will find the issue if you add a console.log statement like this:

```
async function loadMeetups() {
  const response = await api.get(`list/${match.params.id}`);
  console.log(response, response.data)
  setMeetups(response.data);
}
```

to avoid this error, verify response.data is an array

```
async function loadMeetups() {
  const response = await api.get(`list/${match.params.id}`);
  // if response or response.data is undefined, set data to empty array 
  const { data = [] } = response || {};
  // verify response.data is an array
  const isArray = Array.isArray(data)
  isArray && setMeetups(data);
}
```